# Highest power of a number that divides a larger number?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Is the method of prime factorization valid for finding
largest power of a number n such that n divides the number x also x>n?

E.g:-

> **Question**: Highest power of 2 that divides $2^2 * 3^3 * 4^4 * 5^5 * 6^6$ ?

**Ans**:      $16$ by using prime factorization for eliminating $2$ as $2^{16}$ will divide $2^2 * 3^3 * 4^4 * 5^5 * 6^6$.

**Steps:**

1. $2^2 * 3^3 * 4^4 * 5^5 * 6^6$.
2. $2^2 * 3^3 * 2^8 * 5^5 * 3^6 * 2^6 $
3. $2^{16} * 3^9 * 5^5 $
4. Now max power of 2 that can divide $2^{16} * 3^9 * 5^5 $ is $2^{16}$ only.

**My doubt is after getting rid of $2^{16}$ from numerator in step 4 we still have 
$3^9 * 5^5$ which can be divided using 2 though we won't get an integral solution so the approach using prime factorization is incorrect ?**

Reference Video:-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNeiXfQ6EAk&list=PLK4eozjPKMfHJCRkHI34sOG7Pk5c31UTq&index=24

Also we cannot make use of calculator for solving this problem can anyone verify the method in the video if possible do describe an alternate method.

Thanks

Comment: If you know a prime factor, it can be efficiently determined which exponent in the prime factorization belongs to it by repeated division. But to determine the maximum exponent is not significantly easier than integer factorization: In particular , no efficient method is known to decide whether a given number is squarefree.

Comment: So as a general case whenever one is to find max possible power of a given number that divides a very large number one should only eliminate the prime factorized version of the large number to get integral solution rather than going for mixed fraction one?

Comment: In practice, I would partially factor the number by trial division upto , lets say, $10^9$. If the number is not too large, more advanced methods can be applied. If the number cannot be completely factored in a reasonable time, we cannot determine the largest exponent for sure. But it is very likely that the number (when not especially constructed) is not divisible by the square of a prime larger than $10^9$, so we can quite safely assume that the partial factorization reveals the correct result.

Comment: Without a calculator, you probably can only sucessfully determine the result, if the number has very small prime factors.

Answer (score 2):

The method of prime factorization is correct, but inefficient.  For example, 
$234525482759285025987250295345695702224252525239458250845205825092502520592$ is rather hard to factor, but it is quite easy to check that it is divisible by $2^4$ but not by $2^5$.

Answer (score 1):

The method of prime factorization is correct, as shown through your first example. The second example you have cited is wrong. $2$ does *not* divide $3^{9} \cdot 5^{5} = 61509375$ because there is no even number in the prime factorization.